# Laravel: Get number of occurrences in table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this query in `Laravel`:

```
Models::select('*')->group_by('user_name')->order_by(DB::raw('count(user_name)'), 'desc')->take(3)->get();
```

It returns **top 3 users** by the number they appear in the table. 
**Q:** How can I also get the count parameter(how many times they appear?)

Current response:

```
array(
    "Tim","John","Luke"
);
```

I need something like this:

```
array(
    array(
        "user" => "Tim",
        "count" => 3
    ),
    array(
        "user" => "John",
        "count" => 2
    ),
    array(
        "user" => "Luke",
        "count" => 1
    )
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the `COUNT` in the select part of the query and alias it, then use that alias in the ordering.

Something like this, perhaps.

```
Models::select('*', DB::raw('count(user_name) AS user_count'))->group_by('user_name')->order_by(DB::raw('user_count'), 'desc')->take(3)->get();
```

Comment: it looks like a good idea, but i get an error :( General error: 1 no such column: count

Comment: Ah that might be because it's a reserved word in MySQL. I'll update my answer, but try using `user_count` instead. You can change it to what you want though.